# How to reduce Ionic 4 compilation time

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic4

I created my new Ionic 4 project, when i run `ionic serve`, it takes about 40 seconds to compile and reload the application.

I tried to update my node.js version to 11.13.0 but nothing changed.

[Specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAGJJ.png)

Comment: What are the specs of your pc?

Comment: Macbook Air 2014
MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: specs of your cpu pls haha ;), you told me like, what car do you have? a blue one

Comment: Processor: 1.4 GHz Inter Core i5, 
Memory: 4 GB 1600 MHz DD3, 
Graphics Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB.

Comment: It's not a PC related issue, definitely compilation time does take longer vs ionic v3. V4 uses Angular Cli to compile and serve, I believe optimisations need to be made there to improve.